# Is there any way to see query statistics/ plan information WITHOUT the showplan permission? (ie without using the 'show actual plan' button)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got to write queries for a database in which I do not have the 'SHOWPLAN' permissions (ie I cannot view query plans)... but I would like to know more information on the queries I'm writing so that I can optimise where possible.

Is there any useful tips/ sys views/ queries/ settings that could help me optimise without using the query plan?

Comment: All the useful system views that could tell you something about the query require even more encompassing rights -- usually `VIEW SERVER STATE`. Just about the only thing that doesn't require more or different rights is `SET STATISTICS IO ON`/`SET STATISTICS TIME ON`. This gives you a very coarse view over what the query is doing and some way to compare, but it's far from optimal, obviously.

Comment: Are you working in a dev environment or on your production server?  If you are working in dev then request `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you very much! I've got IO and Time permissions and that gives me a lot more information then I previously had :)

Comment: @MJH It's a dev environment but has very tight security. I will see about getting view server state permissions

Comment: Any DBA who would give you `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions (which go *across* databases) but wouldn't give you `SHOWPLAN` on the database isn't worthy of the name. And despite being broader, `VIEW SERVER STATE` does not imply `SHOWPLAN`, so that wouldn't make your life much easier -- you'd still have access to query plans through the system views, but that's much less convenient than just getting one for the query as it executes!